# Splitting parts of a long name into different columns of data frame in R

Tags: r, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe:

```
ColA                             ColB
210812_150um_23deg_5sec          3.8 kPa
210812_150um_23deg_30sec         2.9 kPa
210812_150um_L1_7deg_120sec      5.3 kPa
210812_2.5mg_150um_7deg_120sec   6.8 kPa
...
```

What is the easiest way to extract elements from the names in colA (when there is no regular pattern) and split them up into more columns?  So that I will have a df with the following columns?

```
Date     Angle   Time    Pressure
210812   23deg   5sec    3.8 kPa
210812   23deg   30sec   2.9 kPa
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strsplit` here:

```
df_split <-strsplit(df$ColA, "_")[[1]] 
df$Date <- df_split[1]
df$Angle <- df_split[3]
df$Time <- df_split[4]
df$Pressure <- df$ColB
df

                            ColA    ColB   Date Angle Time Pressure
1        210812_150um_23deg_5sec 3.8 kPa 210812 23deg 5sec  3.8 kPa
2       210812_150um_23deg_30sec 2.9 kPa 210812 23deg 5sec  2.9 kPa
3    210812_150um_L1_7deg_120sec 5.3 kPa 210812 23deg 5sec  5.3 kPa
4 210812_2.5mg_150um_7deg_120sec 6.8 kPa 210812 23deg 5sec  6.8 kPa
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(ColA=c("210812_150um_23deg_5sec",
                        "210812_150um_23deg_30sec",
                        "210812_150um_L1_7deg_120sec",
                        "210812_2.5mg_150um_7deg_120sec"),
                 ColB=c("3.8 kPa", "2.9 kPa", "5.3 kPa", "6.8 kPa"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::extract` and pass in regular expressions to extract the interested data.

```
tidyr::extract(df, ColA, c('Date', 'Angle', 'Time'), '(\\d+).*(\\d+deg)_(\\d+sec)')

#    Date Angle   Time   ColB
#1 210812  3deg   5sec 3.8kPa
#2 210812  3deg  30sec 2.9kPa
#3 210812  7deg 120sec 5.3kPa
#4 210812  7deg 120sec 6.8kPa
```

The same regex can be used in base R's `strcapture`.

```
cbind(strcapture('(\\d+).*(\\d+deg)_(\\d+sec)', df$ColA, 
           proto = list(Date = character(), Angle = character(), 
                       Time = character())), df[2])
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("210812_150um_23deg_5sec", "210812_150um_23deg_30sec", 
"210812_150um_L1_7deg_120sec", "210812_2.5mg_150um_7deg_120sec"
), ColB = c("3.8kPa", "2.9kPa", "5.3kPa", "6.8kPa")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R` with `read.csv` and `sub`

```
cbind(read.csv(text = sub("^(\\d+)_.*_(\\d+deg)_(\\d+sec)", "\\1,\\2,\\3", 
    df$ColA), header = FALSE, col.names = c("Date", "Angle", "Time")), df['ColB'])
    Date Angle   Time   ColB
1 210812 23deg   5sec 3.8kPa
2 210812 23deg  30sec 2.9kPa
3 210812  7deg 120sec 5.3kPa
4 210812  7deg 120sec 6.8kPa
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("210812_150um_23deg_5sec", "210812_150um_23deg_30sec", 
"210812_150um_L1_7deg_120sec", "210812_2.5mg_150um_7deg_120sec"
), ColB = c("3.8kPa", "2.9kPa", "5.3kPa", "6.8kPa")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```